# How to address a rate limiting API?

Tags: python, rest, api, rate-limiting

I have ~12000 requests that needs to be made to an API that is rate limiting to 100 requests per minute per token.  I can pull 100 requests in <= 20 seconds  Assuming I am only using 1 token, am I lower bounded to this script taking two hours to run or is there an optimal strategy I am not seeing?

Naive first approach is to make 100 requests and then wait 61 seconds.  I highly doubt this is optimal.  How would this 100 requests per minute typically be counted?  Would it be computed every "calendar" minute (e.g. I am made 100 requests at 12:01:39 finishing at 12:01:59 would I then be able to make another 100 requests at 12:02:01?)  Or would it be dynamically computed in that every request could not have more than 99 requests in the previous 60 seconds from its time stamp otherwise it throws an error?

Naive first attempt:

```
for task_id in task_IDs:
        if (counter % 100) == 0 and counter != 0:
            time.sleep(61)
           CODE
        else:
            CODE
```

Would love to decrease the amount of time it takes this script to run.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the API you are using? Different APIs use different methods

Comment: It's not going to make a whole lot of difference which way it's calculated. Even if you can exploit "calendar minutes" you might save a whole 20 seconds.

Comment: @Dallan I forgot to mention it is a REST API.

Comment: @Blorgbeard You are probably correct.  My thought on this was to determine if having an evenly distributed sleep period between each request (e.g. time.sleep(0.3)) rather than have a consolidated sleep at the beginning/end.